# Why should I use redux async actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my current code base actions are dispatched from a few stateful components or separated "services" that listen for user or both sensor and real world events. This is a `react-native` application built with redux.

The rest of the code is normally stateless component that represent the state of the app, as recommended. However I have not yet used the [Redux Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) proposal from https://redux.js.org, which I normally follow.

Even though I know it is best practice to keep as many components as stateless as possible, Async Actions and using middleware seems to overcomplicate a relatively simple task, like login an user from input.

Is it worth it? Is there any other reason why I should use an async actions flow?

Comment: how do you intend to do the login otherwise? Requests are async? I don't think it's possible to get away without async, so I'd invest the time to understand how that works - it's a bit frustrating at first, but not that complicated.

Comment: With a stateful component you can handle pretty much all the steps and on fulfillment emit an `rememberUser` action

Comment: sorry, ignore my first comment - the question is really good and the creator of redux has already given an answer to that

Comment: Thanks @leo, could not find it before